# How is the integration time set for a camera?

Tags: embedded, clock, camera, integrator

I using the [TSL1401R-LF Linescan Camera Module](http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf/58/61/586128/tsl1401r-lf.pdf), which reads in a 1 X 128 line of pixels, and I'm having trouble understanding how the integration time is set for this device.

I understand from page 9 that the minimum integration time is a constent that results from a function of the clock speed, but I don't fully understand when this integration period takes place.

According to the timing waveform (Figure 1 on Page 5) the integration period appears to be set after the first 18 clock cycles. Does this mean that the integration period is set while the camera is outputting pixels?

[image: TSL1401R-LF Timing Diagram]

How is that even possible? Also does this mean that in order to achive the minimum delay time I would have to take that time and divide it across those remaining 110 clock cycles (i.e. 307 ns for a total of 33.75 us)?

Comment: You had asked this question before.  I gave an answer and explained the data-sheet and then you subsequently deleted the whole question along with the answer. The whole premise of the stack exchange format is to collect questions and answers for future reference. The reason most people donate their time here is that they know that they will not just be answering one persons' question but , hopefully, many peoples problems in the future. The correct action on your very first question should have been to build on that question with more refined questions.

Comment: What you should have also done is ask for clarification if you didn't understand. After your deletion I saw no reason to invest any more time on answering your questions.  Want to know what the kicker is for you? I have designed many of these types of devices, and know precisely what is going on inside there.

Comment: @placeholder I was told to repost the quest using the guidelines provided in the "How To Ask" section. This question is more straightforward and clear and I figured that it would benefit the stack exchange community more. Sorry if I've made you mad.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker: I am pretty sure you were told to edit the question so it fits the guidelines better, because this is how we roll here

Comment: @placeholder So what should I do now? Should I undelete the old question and edit it? I'm new the community and not totally sure of how things work.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker I'm not mad or angry for that matter. Un deleting now will mean that you will have asked multiple times, which will is also not cool. Let me look at it.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker brought the old answer forward and cleaned it up.

Answer (score 2):

It's a crappy datasheet. As you had noted before:

> According to the data-sheet the integration time is supposed to go between the "SI (Start Integration) positive pulse and the HOLD positive pulse". At the same time it says "the SI and HOLD pins tied together" so I'm confused

It is written as if the Hold signal is on the pin but in reality (from page 2:)

[image]

It is clearly an internally generated signal.

What you're probably not getting is that the **analog read out is the data from the previous integration period**.  The device is integrating the newest image whilst you are reading out the previous one.

You can see this from the timing diagram. I've added in a red arrow showing that the "integrating" just under the \$t_{int}\$ follows in the next line period.

[image]

and this is apparent from the pixel structure as well. There is an integration capacitor as well as a hold capacitor.

[image]

SO the key sentence you should care about is this: (from page 2)

[image]

What that means is that to get longer integration times, you will need to stop the clock and wait.  That means that your line rate will go up as well, but if you are running at max line rate then you are stuck with a fixed integration period.

Of note is that you *may* need to stop the clock at the end of the read out. i.e. extending \$t_{qt}\$.  OR you may be able to keep it free running and then start the next sequence with the SI pulse.  Dig through the data-sheet with your new knowledge or experiment.

The internal sequence of events inside the chip is:

- On the SI pulse, 1st transfer the recently integrated values into hold capacitors, and start ready out in sequence from pixel one throughN.  In parallel reset the pixels ready for a new integration. This resetting takes 18 clock cycles.

After 18 clock cycles start integrating. This integration then happens in parallel with the presently ongoing readout (from pixel 19 onwards).

- Once the last pixel clocks out you have to wait \$t_{qt}\$ until hitting SI again.  At this stage all the old pixels are read out but the integration is still happening.  If you delay the start of SI then the integration extends.

NOTE: that the end of the integration ends with the rising edge of SI.

Comment: What do you mean by stopping my clock and waiting? Is that like adding a `delayMicroseconds()` at the end of the loop that outputs the pixels? Also what is the line rate?

Comment: @CrystalPritzker stopping or halting at a low level.  I don't know what your code segment DealyMicroseconds does so I can't answer. Or you _might_ be able keep the clock running..  The line rate is the inverse of the SI rising edge to SI rising edge.

Comment: If the integration ends with the rising of SI could I include a HIGH SI command at the end of my `readPixels()` method to make that the end of the integration period?